# Detect value change in custom MutableMapping class with unkown depth

Tags: python, wrapper

I'm implementing a wrapper for a config file (json) with the abstract base class `MutableMapping`. The code is shown below:

```
import collections
import json


class ConfigWrapper(collections.MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self._data = None
        self.file_path = file_path
        self._read()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._data[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if self._data[key] != value:
            self._data[key] = value
            self._commit()

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del(self._data[key])

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._data)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def _read(self):
        with open(self.file_path) as file:
            self._data = json.load(file)

    def _commit(self):
        with open(self.file_path, "w") as file:
            json.dump(self._data, file, indent=4)
```

I want my wrapper to automatically save changes to the config file if `__setitem__` is invoked:

```
config = ConfigWrapper("afile.json")
config["key"] = "value"  # first case
config["section"]["key"] = "value"  # second case
```

The first case works just fine. The second case however doesn't trigger `_commit()` because the `__setitem__` method of the standard dict `_data` is used.

The json file may contain nested dicts with unknown depth.

**Question:** How would I solve this problem even if wanted to commit a change in say `config["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"] = "value"`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to make all of the nested containers also be ConfigWrappers instead of plain dicts.

Comment: I thought about that too. The problem is: each subsequent ConfigWrapper wouldn't write the entire config file and I'd loose all data not contained inside the nested ConfigWrapper.

Edit: How would I even convert the plain dicts to a custom dict?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you were committing on every modification.  Basically you will need to create more communication between container and contained objects, so that an inner container "knows" its parent and will ask the parent to commit instead of doing so itself.  Depending on what you're using this for, you might want to rethink committing on every modification; that will likely be inefficient for sizable config files.